# PostgreSQL Insert BYTEA into Database using Stored Procedure

Tags: postgresql

I try to create a sql script to insert BYTEA into a Database. In my Programm i use a method i wrote. Here is the code

```
    Database db = new Database("connection String");
    File file = new File("path to file");
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
    PreparedStatement prepStmt = db.createPreparetStatement("INSERT INTO file VALUES(?,?)");
    prepStmt.setInt(1,1);
    prepStmt.setBinaryStream(2, inputStream, file.length());
    prepStmt.executeUpdate();
    prepStmt.close();
    inputStream.close();
```

This works fine but now i need to do this in a sql script. There is my Problem. I dont know how to store a File into Database using a sql script.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertFileToDatabase(id INTEGER)
    RETURNS void AS $$
    BEGIN
    INSERT INTO file VALUES (?, ?);
    -> HOW DO I INSERT BYTEA HERE <-
    END;
    $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution works for me:

```
    INSERT INTO [TABLENAME]([COLUMN1], [COLUMN2]) VALUES(1, pg_read_binary_file([FILE]))
```

Relative Path is not allowed. The File have to be Stored in Postgres Data Directory